# Get the row and column for a cell in a named range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

Given a cell that exists in a named range, what's the cleanest way to get the row and column numbers for that cell inside the named range? In other words, I want the row and column number relative to the named range.

I know I can:

1. get the size of the named range using ROWS and COLUMNS
2. get the absolute row and column for a cell cell using ROW and COLUMN
3. calculate the relative row and column using #1 and #2 above

But is there any better way?

Comment: What do you mean? What's in the cell? How is the cell selected so you need the position? What is the goal?

Comment: I'm using INDEX (array form) to retrieve a cell value in a named range. I want to highlight the cell being retrieved using conditional formatting. The column and row values used in INDEX are exposed in the worksheet, so they are readily available.

Comment: if you're finding the value already, just use `=CELL("address",A1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CELL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx) function if you know where the cell is. `=cell("address",A1)`